# How can I measure laptop power consumption to optimise battery life?

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, power-management

I have seen devices like the SteamDeck and ROG Ally offer power settings that allow you to limit the watt consumption of the device. They also have live sensor readings telling you the current watt usage (which I guess could be used in lieu of hard watt limits to figure out the most power efficient settings).

I have a long flight coming up and want to maximise the battery life of my laptop (Windows 10 on Dell Precision 5570 - similar to Dell XPS). I will be playing video games, watching movies and probably coding as I try to fight off the boredom.

I have a vague reading of power consumption on a per-application level from Windows task manager - but it's not useful and I haven't yet found something that on a system level saying something like "you are currently using 30W".

I've been looking through MSI Afterburner and HWInfo (I know of them but have never used them) and don't see anything indicating current power consumption.

How can get a live, preferably history graphed, read-out of system power draw?

Comment: If you need software, always check out NirSoft. E.g. https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_information_view.html & https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/battery_history_view.html

Comment: If you are willing to use PowerShell you could use for example 
https://techgenix.com/powershell-check-laptop-battery/ & 
https://blog.technotesdesk.com/2011/07/28/powershell-get-info-on-laptop-battery/

Comment: @Gantendo, you should make the powershell comment into an answer

Comment: @David, I would have thought it was simply to stop anything you are not using.  How are the figures going to help you ?  Some services and programs have to run anyway.  And most of the power is used by the screen, especially if its touch screen.  So, dim it down.

Comment: @RohitGupta If you'd like you can turn it in to an answer.